# Find that values that are immediately below a given set of values and return the entry from another variable

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
a <- c(10, 20, 30)
c <- c(1, 50, 100)

df1 <- data.frame(cbind(a, b, c))

x <- c(80, 30, 15)
z <- c(10, 46, 99)

df2 <- data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))
```

I want to find the values in c that are immediately below the values in z, and then return the equivalent values in a.

So matching z to c will give me the locations: 1, 1, 2, and I want to output those locations from a (i.e 10, 10, 20)

Edit: For each value in z I want to find the location of the value that is below it in c, then return the value in a based on that location

Comment: Unclear. Please try and explain it better. What do you mean *find the values in c that are immediately below the values in z*

Comment: For each value in z I want to find the location of the value that is below it in c, then return the value in a that corresponds to that location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` with the comparison `<`. Then `colSums` should add the TRUEs and give you your answer **given that df1 is ordered on c**, i.e.

```
colSums(outer(df1$c, df2$z, `<`))
#[1] 1 1 2
```

or

```
df1$a[colSums(outer(df1$c, df2$z, `<`))]
#[1] 10 10 20
```

Comment: This gives the *count* of values less than each `z` value. It seems like the question is asking for the *index* of the closest `c` value which is less than the given `z` value (I'm thinking this because the word "location" is used). The results of these two questions happen to coincide, but if you want the outcome described in the previous sentence you can use `apply(outer(df2$z, df1$c, `-`), 1, function(x) which.min(x[x>0]))` for the first part.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan That is exactly what it does. The number of values is actually the row number (sum(values) == 3 corresponds to 3rd row) **given that df1 is ordered on c**. Maybe I should clarify that in my answer.